# Unity lens - what is 'locked-scopes'

Tags: unity, lenses, scopes

Pulling up the .dconf editor GUI, under unity/lenses, there is the 'locked-scopes' field.
What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is a setting that is not active.

Here you can click on a scope and make it either active or inactive:

[image]

The "locked-scopes" has a description "List of scope IDs that the user will see as installed and won't be able to enable nor disable."

The scopes shown are the ones that are installed. You can toggle all of them.

I would assume this means scopes that have been added to this list can not be set active or inactive. (Plus if it is in the "hidden-scopes" it will not be shown and either be enabled or disabled based on the "disabled-scopes").

But it looks like it is not an active setting.

Comment: I believe it works but may require a log out/in (or unity restart, log out is easier

Comment: @doug oh good one :) edit: nope sorry :(

Comment: I added 'files-recoll.scope', hoping to keep it as a static scope that terms are always sent to.  First impressions are that it doesn't do anything.